# HTML within Javascript Function Not Working Properly

Tags: javascript, html, function, textarea

I am using the following JavaScript function:

```
function Projects()
{
    var PrjTb1 = "<input type=text id=PrjNme size=100/>"
    var PrjTb2 = "<textarea rows=5 col=200 wrap=hard></textarea>"
    var Info = "1. Project or activity name:<br>" + PrjTb1 + "<br><br>2. Project or activity description:<br>" + PrjTb2 
    if (document.getElementById('PrjNo').value == 1)
    {
        document.getElementById('AllPrj').innerHTML = "<b>Project or activity 1.</b><br><br>" + Info
    }
}
```

This function executes well, after an `onclick` event; however, certain portions of the HTML within the declared variables are not working.  For example, within the variable `PrjTb2`, my textarea's rows and columns do not change.  Also, I cannot add the HTML tags `<dd>` and `</dd>` anywhere within the variables to create an indentation.  What is interesting is that both the textarea properties and the HTML tags, `<dd>` and `</dd>`, work within the body of my form, just not in my JS function.  Would anyone know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Please can you edit your code to properly format your javascript in a code block?

Comment: This isn't quite related to the question but you _really_, shouldn't use <b> tags. Also, you might want to write you line break this way <br/>.

Check this great post on 10 things to avoid in HTML : http://line25.com/articles/10-html-tag-crimes-you-really-shouldnt-commit

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I am using the <b> tags to make my text bold.  Is there a better way.  I am using the line break tags, <br>, currently.  I am sorry, but I am not sure what you mean by formatting the JS in a code block.

Comment: You should use the tag <strong> instead of <b>. Also if the section you want to use is a header of some sort, try using <h1>, <h2> etc.

Comment: You seem unsure if you are using HTML or XHTML (XHTML requires that attribute values are quoted and uses a / in the tag for EMPTY elements (input, br, img, etc), while HTML makes the quotes optional (sometimes) and doesn't use the / in empty elements)

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your browser is caching your Javascript. Try clearing your cache.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if its the problem, but I'd enclose all your parameters in quotes.

```
<input type=text id=PrjNme size=100/>
```

should really be:

```
<input type='text' id='PrjNme' size='100' />
```

additionally, depending on your Doctype, you may want to change

```
<br>
```

to

```
<br />
```

Things that are allowed in direct HTML are not necessarily allowed using innerHTML. For example, in Firefox, try embedding a form within a form in JS vs html, or in IE, try putting a block element inside an inline element. They both work fine, if you have it in HTML, but if you try it with innerHTML, both browsers will complain.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if your syntax error are due to copying you code here, but here is a couple of things I noticed in your code.

- Are you omitting semi-columns at the end of you lines on purpose?
- HTML proprieties should be surrounded by quotation marks. (Although not necessary)

Also regarding the `<dd></dd>`, did you put those inside a definition list (dl)?

Because they shouldn't be used as standalone tags.

Comment: Attribute values don't need to be quoted. http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.2.2

Comment: Indeed, but it is recommended to do so